# Java: how to declare these variables as 'global'/public?

Tags: java, variables, user-interface, duplicates, declare

Alright guys, this is a pretty basic question, but it's something I'm not completely sure about. In the example below, I have built a simple calculator with two edittexts (for number entry) and two buttons (add and subtract). At the moment, I am having to declare all the variables/components (e.g. buttons, edittexts etc) in both the btnAdd and btnSub OnClick methods. I mean, this is only a really simple program, but having to re-declare all these variables/components (or whatever you call them?) would obviously be really tedious. You can see the code I've currently got:

```
    Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Button btnSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textViewAns = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewAns);//here
            EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);//...
            EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);//...
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());//...
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());//...to here
            int total = num1 + num2;
            textViewAns.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
    });

    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView textViewAns = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewAns);
            EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
            int total = num1 - num2;
            textViewAns.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
    });
```

So you can see all the duplication. What I'm trying to achieve is something like what I'm posting below, though is there anyway that I can do that?

```
    Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Button btnSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    final TextView textViewAns = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewAns);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final int num1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    final int num2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int total = num1 + num2;
            textViewAns.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
    });

    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int total = num1 - num2;
            textViewAns.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
    });
```

At the moment, I get an error in eclipse saying "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method", hence I have added the "final" keyword in front of the variables that I was getting the error for. The problem now though is that whenever I try running the program, it simply freezes as soon as it loads. I'm hopin this will be a quick-fix, though who knows. Anyway, thanks in advance for any answers :)

Comment: Why not use a regular class (instead of an anonymous one)?

Comment: Your second code is perfect - why do you need any keyword along with it

Comment: @NinadPingale The thing is, as soon as I try to run the 2nd code, I just get this message saying "unable to start [Android app name]"...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks. I'll look into that and hopefully be able to solve the problems...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a simple as wrapping your code in a loop then using a switching statement at the end to choose between the two options you could save allot of code that way

```
do {Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Button btnSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    TextView textViewAns = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewAns);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

    if(btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int total = num1 + num2;
            textViewAns.setText(Integer.toString(total));
            break
        }
    });

    else if(btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int total = num1 - num2;
            textViewAns.setText(Integer.toString(total));
            break;
        }
    });


   else continue;
    }while (true)
```

that's been my experience with writing less code for stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to move the code from anonymous class to other class, like:

```
class Foo{
  int things;
  void doSth(){}
}
class Bar{
  final Foo foo = new Foo();
  ...
  btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        foo.doSth();
    }
});
}
```